# How do I post a feed with the facebook graph API that is only visible to a friend's geographical region?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hey guys I am using the facebook graph api to post to a user's wall.

post_params = {"access_token" => "fbaccesstoken", "message" => "wall post"}

url = https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed

Are there any parameters I can include in my post payload that specify the wall post to be shown only to friends in a specified region? (i.e I only want my San Francisco friends to see this post)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you cannot restrict posts to a geographical region. But you can simulate this behavior via the `privacy` parameter, if you have all your San Francisco friends on the same list, for example. See the `posts` [connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts) on the User object and the `privacy` parameter on the [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) object for more information.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I did see the targeting parameter but it applies to fan pages only. I guess I'll have to work around this for now. Thanks a lot.